# Table View does not exist

Tags: java, sql, database, derby

i am using SQuirrel SQL Client Version 3.7 to view my derby database
the username for this connection is umar and password is umar ..

[image: apache derby embedded database connection]

when i run an insert query inside this connection i get the following error

i am using netbeans and it doesn't work there as well my code gives the same error .. what do i do to fix this
[image: Table/View Does Not Exist Error]

here is the statement i use for creating ADMINISTRATORS TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE ADMINSTRATORS(ADMIN_ID BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS         IDENTITY,username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,password VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT ADMIN_PK PRIMARY KEY (ADMIN_ID) )
```

Comment: It has been a while since I've used Squirrel but make sure you have the database selected. I believe it was the "Catalog" dropdown above the query window.

Comment: i ran a query inside netbeans and it worked .. my username is UMAR so i had to write UMAR.ADMINISTRATORS .. and it worked

Comment: why is this .. why didn't it work instead of simply writing ADMINISTRATORS

Answer (score 1):

it was a spelling mistake in my sql query

```
CREATE TABLE ADMINISTRATORS(ADMIN_ID BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS         IDENTITY,username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,password VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT ADMIN_PK PRIMARY KEY (ADMIN_ID) )
```

please someone close this question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not pointing to the database you think you are, try issuing this before your insert:

```
use UMAR
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your JDBC url having your database name ?

Ex.

```
    private static String jdbcURL= "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/UMAR";
```

Comment: jdbc:derby:automobiledb;create=true

Comment: and username is umar and password is umar

Comment: do i need to specify UMAR in the connection string ? but UMAR is the username ?